# Is external CSS able to style the <html> element?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to move my CSS to an external file, but after moving it, the  element is no longer being styled (most noticeably, the background color gradient), although the exact same code worked when it was internal.

Is it possible to style  with external CSS?

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  background: linear-gradient(#33ccff, #33ccff, #00cc66);
  }
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hugh Crank</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body> etc.
```

Comment: Yes. It works. It seems to be all right. Is your path to CSS proper? Also add `type="text/css"` attribute to `link` tag.

Comment: put `background` inside `body` styling.

Comment: @HarshalPatil that's so long been unnecessary

Comment: check if both (css and html) files are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course! You can style the HTML tags by three ways:

i. internal CSS

ii. external CSS

iii. inline CSS.

For external CSS you have to link a new CSS file to your HTML file, and then you can easily add style on HTML by calling those HTML tags by id or class.

Comment: Sorry, it may not be clear in the body of my question, but I linked to my external CSS file correctly. All CSS is applied, except for that which applies to <html>.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#33ccff+0,33ccff+50,00cc66+100 */
  background: #33ccff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #33ccff 0%, #33ccff 50%, #00cc66 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #33ccff 0%, #33ccff 50%, #00cc66 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #33ccff 50%, #00cc66 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33ccff', endColorstr='#00cc66', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hugh Crank</title>
</head>

<body> etc
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to style <html> so the entire viewpoint has the gradient. <body> does not take up the entire screen, therefore the gradient repeats.

Comment: Thats beacuse you have added padding in html. No one adds padding to html, they add padding to body.

Comment: @HughCrank add to body styles `min-height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only your address is not correct. 
If your html file and css file are in different folders you must set css file's address related to your html file.

Check this possible states (X and Y are some folders):

```
Html.html
X/css.css
=> href="x/styles.css"

X/Html.html
css.css
 => href="../styles.css"

Y/X/Html.html
css.css
 => href="../../styles.css"
```

Or try this: `href="/cssFolder/styles.css"` for access root.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="one of above addresses"/>
```

Also, add your css to body instead of html.

---

**Edit** (after your comment):

To do this:

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And now add your own styles to it. You can add all of these styles to your external css file; your way is correct.

Comment: My address is correct. All CSS is applied, except for that which applies to <html>. I want to style <html> so the entire viewpoint has the gradient. <body> does not take up the entire screen, therefore the gradient repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an external css will style your html page unless it is overwritten by an internal or an inline css. The external css file will have to be linked to the html page.

The syntax - `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="abc.css"></head>`.

abc.css is the file name (example).